# How to automatically click an element the contains specific word?

Tags: javascript, dom, click

How do I automatically click a `href` that contains the word 'photo'?

This is the code that I tried but it says 'dom exception'.

```js
document.querySelector('a[href~"/a/photo.php?"]').click();
```

Comment: click is for a manual action, to make a automatic action , you just have to call the function directly